# C# Webforms - How to fix localhost redirect you too many times after login?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, form-authentication

I want to deny anonymous users and allow all authenticated users to access. After successful login, it supposed to redirect to Default page. However, it keep showing error : too many redirects. It seems like it keep redirecting back to login page. Why and how to fix it? Below are my codes, did i missed anything or done anything wrong that cause the problem? Thanks in advance

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(this.txtusername.Text, false);

FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(
                        1,                                      
                        this.txtusername.Text,              
                        DateTime.Now,                           
                        DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(30),            
                        false,                                  
                        Role                  
                        );
 HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie(FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName,
                FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket));
                Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);    
                // the login is successful
                if (Request.QueryString["ReturnUrl"] == null)
                {                        
                    Response.Redirect("~/Default.aspx");                                              
                }                    


<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="30"> </forms>
</authentication>
<authorization>
  <deny users="?" />
  <allow users="*" />
</authorization>
```

Comment: Check if your code has infinite loop with `Response.Redirect`. If it's found, use if-condition before redirect e.g. `if (!HttpContext.Current.Request.Path.EndsWith("Login.aspx", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)) Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")`